# Automatic update of containers on ECS with configuration change

Tags: spring-boot, amazon-ecs, configuration-files, configurationmanager

I am currently deploying some spring boot services to cloud on ECS containers. These containers use application.properties (some properties are common across services like cross cutting items).

When the common properties (or others) change I need to re-create the task definition of each of the service and re-deploy it cyclically.

Is there any better approach (most of these properties are needed on startup and doesn't change often to warrant the need of config server).

As per my understanding, even with AWS AppConfig and with minimum code change even if I [write to disk](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2023/12/aws-appconfig-agent-write-backups-permission-mapping/) and point my container to the same, still I have to do that for all services and re-deploy.

Is there any better way to handle it.

Thanks

Comment: With AWS AppConfig you would just have to restart the containers. You could do that by issuing an ECS Service update with the "force redeploy" flag. You would not have to build new container images and update the task definition in that scenario.

Comment: Thank you for the update. So is the understanding correct that once I run force redeploy of the service, it will also pick up the latest s3 environment ?

Comment: If your application picks that setting up on startup, then yes if you force redeploy, causing all your containers to be stopped and replaced with new containers, then obviously those new containers will pick up the new settings.